# Google Drive PHP SDK saves an Untitled file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm using the following function to insert a file:

```
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);
  if ($file->parentId != null) {
    $parentsCollectionData = new DriveFileParentsCollection();
    $parentsCollectionData->setId($file->parentId);
    $file->setParentsCollection(array($parentsCollectionData));
  }
  try {
    $datafile = file_get_contents($filename);
    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $datafile,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));
    print_r($datafile);
  return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }}
```

The function uploads the file, but without a title. It creates an "Untitled" file in my Google Drive. I'm using a v2 of API.

print_r($file):

```
DriveFile Object
(
[mimeType] => text/plain
[thumbnailLink] => 
[__labelsType:protected] => DriveFileLabels
[__labelsDataType:protected] => 
[labels] => 
[__indexableTextType:protected] => DriveFileIndexableText
[__indexableTextDataType:protected] => 
[indexableText] => 
[etag] => 
[lastModifyingUserName] => 
[writersCanShare] => 
[id] => 
[title] => test.txt
[ownerNames] => 
[sharedWithMeDate] => 
[lastViewedByMeDate] => 
[__parentsType:protected] => ParentReference
[__parentsDataType:protected] => array
[parents] => 
[exportLinks] => 
[originalFilename] => 
[description] => Description
[editable] => 
[kind] => 
[quotaBytesUsed] => 
[fileSize] => 
[createdDate] => 
[md5Checksum] => 
[embedLink] => 
[alternateLink] => 
[permissionsLink] => 
[modifiedByMeDate] => 
[downloadUrl] => 
[__userPermissionType:protected] => Permission
[__userPermissionDataType:protected] => 
[userPermission] => 
[fileExtension] => 
[selfLink] => 
[modifiedDate] => 
)
```

print_r($createdFile):

```
Array
(
    [kind] => drive#file
    [id] => 0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk
    [etag] => "ia2FSHMEjvcFQvtI43H5NSXK_wk/MTM0MTI1MjU5MzA5Nw"
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk
    [alternateLink] => https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk/edit
    [permissionsLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk/permissions
    [title] => Untitled
    [mimeType] => multipart/related; boundary=1411182904
    [labels] => Array
        (
            [starred] => 
            [hidden] => 
            [trashed] => 
            [restricted] => 
            [viewed] => 1
        )

    [createdDate] => 2012-07-02T18:09:53.402Z
    [modifiedDate] => 2012-07-02T18:09:53.097Z
    [modifiedByMeDate] => 2012-07-02T18:09:53.097Z
    [lastViewedByMeDate] => 2012-07-02T18:09:53.097Z
    [parents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => drive#parentReference
                    [id] => 0ALfGO53dEJzbUk9PVA
                    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk/parents/0ALfGO53dEJzbUk9PVA
                    [parentLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0ALfGO53dEJzbUk9PVA
                    [isRoot] => 1
                )

        )

    [downloadUrl] => https://doc-14-4c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6eprdcqtdmlpnd2gmvdr6jlnlagf8s6i/9fqrnka0tci3gs14tff8ur996h1b74ip/1341252000000/15694289178108491958/15694289178108491958/0B7fGO53dEJzbUVJwVEFRc09PMkk?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true
    [userPermission] => Array
        (
            [kind] => drive#permission
            [etag] => "ia2FSHMEjvcFQvtI43H5NSXK_wk/9STkNeCmz61YXorH3hoJimnEgfM"
            [id] => current
            [role] => owner
            [type] => user
        )

    [originalFilename] => Untitled
    [fileExtension] => 
    [md5Checksum] => 3e7959340ef7f8a8d24e5b9ad3daafe8
    [fileSize] => 407
    [quotaBytesUsed] => 407
    [ownerNames] => Array
        (
            [0] => Myszczuk
        )

    [lastModifyingUserName] => Myszczuk
    [editable] => 1
    [writersCanShare] => 1
)
```

Comment: Could you show us the result of `print_r($file);` and `print_r($createdFile);`? Also, are you using v1 or v2 of the API?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, I'm using the code snippet provided [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) (slightly different from what you're using) and it works perfectly for me (the title is correctly set)... Can you make sure you're using the latest version of the PHP client library (sync from the repo)?

Answer (score 1):

Just do what Alain said, **update or checkout the newest client library** from Google.

Comment: Here the link: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%253Fstate%253Dclosed - Because sometimes, the new release isn't located where you think.