# PHP Google Drive API - File Upload Only As "Untitled"-File Or Just Without Content

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am searching for a solution to upload files from my root server directly to my Google Drive-account via PHP.

Authorisation is working fine, but when I try to transfer a file (for example "test.jpg"), it just creates a file named "Untitled" in Google Drive. It also ignores the folder where to save it in and creates it in the main-folder.

If I use the same save-function, with the same parameters, but just leave the file-content empty everything works fine. The file gets created with the correct filename in the correct subfolder - everything I want - but without the filedata.

Is it perhaps a configuration-problem?

I am using the following code (see the php-example at the bottom) for transfering the files:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Many thanks for your answers!!

Comment: Can you make sure you synced to the latest version of the client library from the [repository](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/checkout)? I can't reproduce the issue but I remember another question similar to this one (though I can't find it anymore).

Comment: Here the link Alain was probably trying to find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284700/google-drive-php-sdk-saves-an-untitled-file

Answer (score 0):

Just got an answer on my own related question, just make a copy of the files here http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%253Fstate%253Dclosed - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert ... for creating *new files*.

Method "update" provides functionality for creating new revisions or overwriting *existing files*.

Comment: Anyway when he asked, the insert function wasn't working at that time - I had the same problem. Since the new api, that problem is solved.

Comment: Well, also had initial issues with the api-wrapper downloaded from the web - once checked out from SVN much more suddenly worked :)