# Redirection with the PHP API 0.6 failing (copy a file from drive to my own server)

Tags: php, google-drive-api, elgg

I've got a copy of the latest PHP API (which apparently appeared some hours ago - 0.6) [here.](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

It's solving my problem as explained here: [Google Drive SDK: Inserting a file results in Untitled in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633722/google-drive-sdk-inserting-a-file-results-in-untitled-in-php)

But right now, I've a problem of redirection after copying the file from Drive to my server (which was fine with the current API (0-5) where the files were still called apiDriveService for example). The copy itself is working, no worry about it here. But I can't send the user where I want.

**I'm using Elgg 1.7 and its function forward** (which is working fine everywhere on the site and as mentionned above, with the 0.5 API).

If you need more information, don't hesitate to tell me. I'll try your suggestions but be aware that I will be on vacations next week, so, I may be not checking or answering right away.

EDIT: Nevermind, we found the problem: there was a space before a

```
<?php
```

in one of the files I've copy pasted.

Comment: Could explain what you mean by "can't send the user where I want"? Are you trying to redirect the user to a specific web page? Is that related to the Drive API?

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the API or not, that's why it's also tagged elgg. But, yeah, once the copy is done, the user is redirected to his files folder on the website (not towards the Drive part of the site). All that I know is that it was working fine with the php client 0.5 but I need the 0.6 for sending a file from our site to Drive. I think it's header related but I'm not sure.